# Mocking JIRA java client objects using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, jira-rest-java-api

We are integrating our application with JIRA, to create an issue with attachment.

**Method 1:**

```
    public JSONObject createIssue() {
    
                IssueRestClient issueClient = restClient.getIssueClient();
                MetadataRestClient metadataClient = restClient.getMetadataClient();
                
                Map<String, Long> priorityMap = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, Long> issueMap = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, String> fieldsMap = new HashMap<>();
    
                // To get the list of all types of priorities
                metadataClient.getPriorities().claim().forEach(priorityType -> priorityMap.put(priorityType.getName(), priorityType.getId()));
                // To get the list of all issue types
                metadataClient.getIssueTypes().claim().forEach(issueType -> issueMap.put(issueType.getName(), issueType.getId()));
                // To get the list of all fields, which includes the custom fields
                metadataClient.getFields().claim().forEach(fieldType -> fieldsMap.put(fieldType.getName(), fieldType.getId()));

// skipped the remaining code


    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
public void addAttachmentToIssue(String issueId, InputStream inputStream, String fileNameWithExtension) {

Issue issue = null;

IssueRestClient issueClient = restClient.getIssueClient();

  Promise<Issue> promiseIssue = issueClient.getIssue(issueId);
  issue = promiseIssue.claim();

  issueClient.addAttachment(issue.getAttachmentsUri(), inputStream, fileNameWithExtension);

}
```

I'm writing unit tests using Mockito.

```
public class JIRATest{

    @InjectMocks
    JIRAService mockJiraService;    
    JiraRestClient mockJiraRestClient;  
    IssueRestClient mockIssueRestClient;
    Promise mockPromise;    
    Issue mockIssue;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockJiraService = new JIRAService();
        mockJiraRestClient = mock(JiraRestClient.class);
        mockIssueRestClient = mock(IssueRestClient.class);              
        mockJiraService.setRestClient(mockJiraRestClient);
        mockPromise = mock(Promise.class);
        mockIssue = mock(Issue.class);

    }

@Test
public void addAttachmentTest(){

        Mockito.when(mockJiraRestClient.getIssueClient()).thenReturn(mockIssueRestClient);
        
        Mockito.when(mockIssueRestClient.getIssue("DCU")).thenReturn(mockPromise);
        Mockito.when(mockPromise.claim()).thenReturn(mockIssue);
        Mockito.when(mockIssueRestClient.addAttachment(any(), any(), any()));
        
        String webSite = "https://www.google.com";
         URL url = new URL(webSite);
             InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        mockJiraService.addAttachmentToIssue("issueId", stream, "lowes-webpage.html");
}

}
```

How to mock these below objects, so that i wanted to use it in `thenReturn()` of Mockito?

```
1. Promise<Issue>
2. metadataClient.getPriorities() return Promise<Iterable<Priority>> 
3. metadataClient.getPriorities().claim() return Iterable<Priority>
4. metadataClient.getIssueTypes() return Promise<Iterable<IssueType>>
5. metadataClient.getPriorities().claim()  return Iterable<IssueType>
6. metadataClient.getFields() return Promise<Iterable<Field>>
7. metadataClient.getFields().claim() return Iterable<Field>
```